# Saving each iteration as separate excel file using panda dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there a way to save a document from each iteration as separate excel file? I am looping through test list, and would like to save *new_file* for every element of a *test*.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    test= ['ALPI', 'BHMT']
    for i in test:
        new_file=df[df['Genes'].str.contains(i)]
        new_file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)
        writer.save()
```

Code above creates a new_file just for first element of a *test* list ('ALPI').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an excel writer for saving each dataframe on different files (only if you want to save everything on the same file, but different sheets).

```
test= ['ALPI', 'BHMT']
for i in test:
    new_file=df[df['Genes'].str.contains(i)]
    new_file.to_excel(i + ".xlsx")
```